# Server Level Trigger Breaks CRM

Tags: sql-server, dynamics-crm, database-trigger

We've just implemented a server level trigger on our SQL Server 2014 instance. It's working as expected ... except it breaks the Dynamics CRM which is hosted on premise on the same server.

In short, no developer is able to alter an entity. Whenever they do, they get this error:

> A SQL Server error occurred.
>   Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support: #EFBBF1B9

If we disable the trigger then it's fine. There is nothing in the SQL Server logs. And the trigger itself is a pretty standard auditing type trigger.

Any ideas?

Comment: It may help to post the trigger code

Comment: Security context of user that made the original ddl statement - is this a scenario you have to use GRANT CONTROL SERVER so that the origianl context can run this trigger.   similar to  WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER   ( I am just throwing stuff out there)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Leaving this out there for people in the future. It was due to permissions.

I gave the user that CRM logs on to db_owner rights, and it worked, so I'm going to work backwards from here and find the minimum they need.

Comment: On Prem CRM creates several accounts that have just enough minimum privileges - there are several accounts that perform "on be half of" actions.  There may be more than one account you have to do this "db owner" change to.  Also you have just elevated an account that was purposely restricted by MS.

Comment: yeah, I agree I won't be leaving it like this. I just wanted to put out that the solution is permissions - because the error I posted says virtually nothing, and there is nothing in the SQL logs to say it either.